# Warum schreibt man "Das ist ein riesen Aufwand."?

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective, nominative

Warum schreibt man diesen Satz so:

> Das ist ein riesen Aufwand

Das ist ja Nominative.
Aus meiner Sicht sollte das so sein:

> Das ist ein rieser Aufwand

oder

> Das ist ein riesiger Aufwand

Ist "riesen" ein Adjektive?

Comment: Man schreibt nicht "riesen Aufwand". Man schreibt "Riesenaufwand".

Comment: "Das ist ein riesiger Aufwand" ist auch korrekt, das Wort *rieser* gibt es hingegen nicht ...

Comment: @IQV, schreib das als Antwort dann bitte :)

Comment: "Riesen" ist hier der Genitiv von "Riese". Analog: *Das ist ein Wahnsinnsaufwand*.

Comment: Entfernt verwandt: Video "Das ist Klasse/klasse." http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/rechtschreibung/klasse-rechtschreibung.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either say: [Riesenaufwand](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Riesenaufwand.html), which is a noun in its own.

Or you can also say *Das ist ein riesiger Aufwand* if you want to describe the kind of effort more precisely.

Comment: I did not get it completely, what is the difference bet ween "Riesenaufwand" und "riesiger Aufwand"?

Comment: Choice in style...

Comment: @Denis and rules if morphology (word formation) add the n suffix to “Riese”.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Daniel's answer, and with respect to Denis' additional question what's the difference between *Riesenaufwand* and *riesiger Aufwand*:

a) Style

In all languages people can chose how to express something, without the "core meaning" of what is being said being different. "Riesenaufwand" (and similar contraptions such as Riesenärger, Riesenmist, Riesenfest, Riesenstau etc.) are typical for sloppy oral communication. With *riesiger Aufwand* you are somewhat more into the direction of formal speech (although it is still somewhat sloppy). Very formal would be *ungeheurer Aufwand* or *außerordentlich großer Aufwand*-

b) Here is an additional observation regarding evolution of language:

Indeed *Riesenaufwand* is a concatenation of two nouns (Riesen + Aufwand). However, this combination is used so frequently in everyday common language, that, in my opinion, people have started "feeling" it as an adjective, and therefore increasingly often they write it as "riesen Aufwand" thus re-interpreting the "riesen" as an adjective with exceptional morphology (different case suffixes than usual).

Honestly speeking, I myself am doing this sometimes, quite on purpose, especially when rendering oral language e.g. in transcripts.

c) Similar expressions (where the first noun tends to take on the funtion of an adjective) are

> Affenzirkus, Affentheater
>
> Schweinearbeit / Sauarbeit
>
> Heidentheater, Heidenschlamassel

(Note for pronunciation that emphasis is usually on the second noun, not the "adjektive-ish" one): Riesen**ä**rger, Schweine**a**rbeit, Sau**a**rbeit, Heidenthe**a**ter. An exception is strangely **A**ffenzirkus, **Affen**theater. Perhaps **Affen** is still more on the side of a full noun?)

I have not seen this being written "heiden Theater", "sau Arbeit", "affen Zirkus", but as "riesen Aufwand" is becoming popular, the step to "heiden Theater" etc. does not seem so far.

Different, however, is the infamous

> Zwergenaufstand

You would never feel like writing this as "zwergen Aufstand", probably because here not a "very tiny uprising" is meant, rather an "uprising of tiny people".

> 

Answer (score 4):

"Riesen" befindet sich wohl derzeit in einem Übergangsprozess, den ähnliche Wörter wie "super" oder "klasse" schon vollendet haben, nämlich hin zu einem nichtflektierten Adjektiv. Während "super" und "klasse" auch standardsprachlich weitgehend als Adjektive akzeptiert werden, ist die Verwendung von "riesen" als Adjektiv derzeit noch ausschließlich umgangssprachlich. Standardsprachlich müsste man nach wie vor "Riesenaufwand" schreiben.

Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass die weit verbreitet Schreibweise als Adjektiv von der Aussprache her kommt: "Riesenaufwand" hat einen Haupt- und einen Nebenakzent, "riesen Aufwand" hat zwei Hauptakzente. Offenbar wird "riesen" häufig als Adjektiv wahrgenommen und ausgesprochen, und die Schreibung richtet sich mehr und mehr danach.